# win32: waitable event object for GUI messages?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, events, object

Is it possible to create an event object that becomes signalled when GUI message(s) is/are available, like one can create event objects that signal the presence of data on a socket for instance? The idea would be to use a WaitMultipleEvents for either something happening on the GUI or a request arriving on a TCP/IP socket.

I'd delegate the whole client/server comm stuff to a background thread if this weren't a QuickTime app (QuickTime is rather quirky where multithreading is concerned, on win32 at least).

BTW, can one do things like moving/resizing/renaming windows created on another thread, using the dedicated functions - or would that require posting messages explicitly?

Comment: Can you just do this in the Windows message loop? That's effectively what waits for GUI messages (among others).

Comment: If you don't want to fire your event by posting a message to the GUI input queue, (a reasonable approach, as suggested by @RogerRowland), you could use the MsgWaitForMultipleObjects() API to run your Windows message queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no waitable object for messages in your queue, but there is a wait function that will wait for a waitable object *or* a message in your queue.  See [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There is no such event to signal that a Windows message is available. The solution is to get socket notifications in the form of a Windows message instead of an event. WSAAsyncSelect configures this mode in the socket. This let you use your message loop to get both GUI messages and socket notifications, all in one thread.

Comment: Yes, I know - but it appears to be common wisdom _not_ to use that function. Messages can take their time to arrive, and too heavy communication could render the GUI unresponsive. I'm not sure how the approach using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects differs in that aspect, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. Indeed, I was reminded elsewhere of MsgWaitForMultipleObjects, and use that ([code extract:](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=24713551#p24713551))

Comment: Why did you add this answer at all when Adrian says the same and more? And why did you not accept Adrian's answer?